# pg-promise method for PostgreSQL void function

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pg-promise

When executing a PostgreSQL function that `RETURNS void`, `db.none()` rejects with `"No return data was expected."`.

I then use the `db.one()` method, which resolves with the object `{ PS_name: '' }`.

Should I expect PostgreSQL void functions to actually return an empty object? What would be the most appropriate way of handling void functions with `pg-promise`?

Comment: The answer I provided below is no longer valid - see the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer below is no longer valid, as PostgreSQL v11 added support for proper stored procedures, and method [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc) now can only invoke a stored procedure, using the new `CALL` syntax.

---

> What would be the most appropriate way of handling void functions with pg-promise?

Database method [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc).

```
db.proc('proc_name', [param1, param2,...])
    .then(data => {
        /* data = either null or an object */
    })
    .catch(error => {
        /* error */
    });
```

**UPDATE**

> How do you specify the parameter types when using `proc`? i.e., to fix `function foo(unknown) does not exist`? If I do `db.proc('foo($1::int2[])', x)`, then it throws `syntax error at or near "("`.

You can't do it with method [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc), which was created to keep things very simple. If your call requires SQL type casting, you need to execute it as a regular query with the casting inside the template:

```
db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM proc_name($1::int2[], $2, ...)', [param1, param2,...])
    .then(data => {
        /* data = either null or an object */
    })
    .catch(error => {
        /* error */
    });
```

Method [oneOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#oneOrNone) in this context is equivalent in result expectation to method [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc).

Comment: Is the `proc` method SQL injection-safe?

Comment: @Kathandrax yes it is.

Comment: @vitaly-t : How do you specify the parameter types when using proc? I.e., to fix "function foo(unknown) does not exist"? If I do db.proc("foo($1::int2[])", x), then it throws 'syntax error at or near "("'.

Comment: @steamer25 I have added an update with your question ;)